# Permanent redirects by MediaWiki: when?

Tags: mediawiki, hhvm

some time ago I set up a MediaWiki installation with very short URLs like `http://(mydomain)/Page_Title`.

I made sure it worked, even if the page was called */etc*: `http://(mydomain)//etc` opened correctly.

Now I found out that some time ago this stopped working. Instead, MW 1.26 and 1.27 under *HHVM* 3.14.3 and *nginx* 1.10.1 provides an circular permanent redirect (code 301) to `http://(mydomain)//etc` in response for `http://(mydomain)//etc` and even `http://(mydomain)/w/index.php?title=/etc`. The redirect is issued not by *nginx* but by *HHVM* and therefore by *MediaWiki*.

I do not know whether I have broken something in *MediaWiki* configuration (it's huge, so I will not provide it) or some new bug has been introduced into *MediaWiki* or *HHVM*.

My question is: where are the places (files or classes) in *MediaWiki* core code that can reply with 301 code to a simple page view, so I can look which configuration settings affect this behaviour?

Comment: It would be more interesting, what the target of the redirect is, so please provide the whole headers or at least just the `Location:` header ;) Btw.: Nearly any code can emit a 301-redirect, but it has to do it explicitly (`OutputPage::redirect()` emits a 302 redirect by default), so a simple search can help. It seems there're only 2 places with 301 redirects in MediaWiki core....

Comment: ... Both of them seems to be unrelated (https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/bd619f02525f27beba1b17d6dc1ab23a3b0e12cc/includes/MediaWiki.php#L234 -> external links, so called external Interwiki) and https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/8f9643d8f9e12b0d0bc592b1af5313ffaed12ba9/includes/specials/SpecialContributions.php#L176 -> RSS/Atom feed redirects).

Comment: While there are many places where redirect can happen, most of the general-purpose redirection code is in `MediaWiki::performRequest()`. In any case, adding some logging calls to `OutputPage::redirect()` is probably your best bet. See `wfDebugLog()` and `wfGetAllCallers()` for convenient caller logging.

Comment: Yes, it is in the new file `include/MediaWiki.php` (line 344-348 in my case), ultimately caused by lines 791-797 of `include/WebRequest.php`. Thank you; looks like I am filing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the places that return a permanent redirect are in a new (since *MediaWiki* 1.26.3) file `include/MediaWiki.php`: lines 230, 286, 341, 353.

In my case, the hack I previously added to `LocalSettings.php` to deal with ultra-short URLs (see below) contributed to the endless redirect. Whithout it, the redirect woud be: `http[s]://(mydomain)//etc` → `http[s]://etc`, which is totally wrong to, but not circular.

The hack:

```
// This is for titles starting with /: [[/etc]] → "//etc" → "/.//etc".
// Set merge_slashes off in nginx config!
$wgHooks ['GetLocalURL'] [] = function ($title, &$url, $query) {
    if (mb_substr ($title->getText (), 0, 1) === '/'
     && $title->getNamespace () === 0
     && !MWNamespace::hasSubpages (0 /* the same as $title->getNamespace () but faster */)
    ) {
        $url = '/.' . $url;
    }
    return true;
 };
```

URL was "normalised": in lines 792-799 of `include/WebRequest.php`: several leading slashes there are replaced with one; then `MediaWiki::tryNormaliseRedirect ()` saw that the "normalised" URL is not equal to the original one and served 301.

This looks like a rather old bug in `WebRequest::getGlobalRequestURL()`, which was unmasked only in MediaWiki 1.26.3; so I filed it: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T141444.